# В рамке есть фон картинки

Tags: css

У меня есть рамка стиля CSS, я туда сделал фон из картинки, но он выходит из границ рамки. Как это предотвратить?

Comment: в div все засунь =)

Answer (score 1):

На корневой элемент поставь `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Можно прописать в стиле объекта, к которому применяется рамка либо свойство

```
overflow: hidden;
```

как говорилось выше, либо

```
overflow: auto;
```

это чтобы если содержимое не влезает в блок, появлялись полосы прокрутки в самом блоке.